# converting array to many objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, type-conversion

I have an array of : `["a","b","c","d"]` and I would like to convert it to many objects with same key "libelle" as in :

```
{
  0 : { "libelle" : "a"},
  1 : { "libelle" : "b"},
  2 : { "libelle" : "c"},
  3 : { "libelle" : "d"}
}
```

I do not want :

```
{
      0 :  "a",
      1 :  "b",
      2 :  "c",
      3 :  "d"
    }
```

Comment: `arr.map(libelle => ({ libelle }))`

Comment: Hello, that is not what I need

Comment: I am looking for an Array(4) within an Array(1), your solution does the opposite

Comment: Please provide valid output, both of these aren't valid arrays. Arrays have [] and only objects have named keys

Comment: His response returns exactly what you requested in your question. If you are getting something different I suggest you post the **exact** code you used. You can use the code snippet button [<>] on here to post executable snippets.

Comment: If this: https://jsfiddle.net/j70a5cm3/ isn't what you want, I don't know what else it can be. It's the closest valid data structure.

Comment: `libelle: Array(4)
0: "a"
1: "b"
2: "c"
3: "d"`
This is what the console logs with that solution , I have been trying it with reduce and Option functions but it doesn't work out. I need the word "libelle" to be infront of every element of the array.     "libelle" : "a" should be an object by itself and pushed to an object that contains all the letters.

Comment: It seems your code is working in the fiddle, I do not know why it does not work for me . Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Check this out!

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const myObj = {};

for(let x in arr){
    myObj[x] = {"libelle": arr[x]}
}
```